# Maximum Reusability for Two Implementations with Different Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a task that includes migrating an API Gateway from Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway. There are two main versions currently: 1.0.1.RELEASE and 2.0.0.RC1. The first version is very basic and I'd have to manually implement filters related to rate limiting, authentication, etc...

While the second version has all the features we need with complete YML support. We have a strict rule in the company to never use beta or RC, and we need the first version of the gateway to be in production within a couple of weeks so there is not enough time to wait for the final release of version 2.

My team-leader specifically asked me to make 2 versions of using version 1.0.1 and 2.0.0 of SCG. How do you implement the module for maximum reusability? I mean I want switching between the two versions to be as easy as possible and I want to reuse as much of the logic as I can. The first thing that came to my mind is simply to create two separate projects. What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Sam! Do you have some kind of version control system like git or svn you use? My suggestion would be to create two different branches, rather than two projects.

Comment: we do yes, we have git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want an easy transition from the version `1.0.1.RELEASE` to `2.0.0.RC1` of some dependency.

I would approach it as follows:

Create 3 modules (or projects):

- `api`
- `bindings-1`
- `bindings-2`

The `api` module contains the API which you'll define to access functions of the dependency.

The `bindings-1` and `bindings-2` both implement what's defined in `api`, but based on the versions `1.0.1.RELEASE` and `2.0.0.RC2` accordingly.

Your code will use the dependency only and exclusively via the `api`. No direct access to the classes and methods provided by the dependency. I would even not include the dependency as a compile-time dependency. You'll then import `bindings-1` or `bindings-2` depending on which version you want to use.

Having a separate `api` will require certain effort. It will seem overengineered. But if you don't do this, bindings to the dependency will diffuse in your code and switching from one version to another will be much more difficult.

With a dedicated `api` you will be forced to crystallize everything you need from the dependency in your `api` - in a version-independent manner.

I would also not develop `bindings-1`/`bindings-2` as SCM branches. It's not like you'll be merging them, so why branches?

Comment: I'll probably be doing it that way